# i got the error "backup failed for Server 'XYZ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS'.how to resolve it

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I get this error

> backup failed for Server 'XYZ-PC\SQLEXPRESS'.

How to resolve it?

```
//Define a Backup object variable.
Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

//Specify the type of backup, the description, the name, and the database to be backed up.
sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "BackUp of:" + "Garment.mdf" + "on" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "FullBackUp";
sqlBackup.Database = "Garment.mdf";

//Declare a BackupDeviceItem
BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem("D:\\SQLBackup" + "Garment.bak", DeviceType.File);
//Define Server connection
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(".\\SQLEXPRESS");
//To Avoid TimeOut Exception
Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
sqlServer.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 60 * 60;

Database db = sqlServer.Databases["Garment.mdf"];

sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

//Add the device to the Backup object.
sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
//Set the Incremental property to False to specify that this is a full database backup.
sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
//Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete.
sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;
sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

//Run SqlBackup to perform the full database backup on the instance of SQL Server.
sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);

//Remove the backup device from the Backup object.
sqlBackup.Devices.Remove(deviceItem);
```

Comment: Is your database really called `garment.mdf` on the server side? Is that the **logical** database name? Highly unlikely - if you want to backup from the server, you need to use the **logical database name** (e.g. `Garment`) - but **NOT** the actual **file name**!

Comment: Do you have logs or whatnot that tell you more about the error/problem? Like, *why* it failed? No more disk space? No access to backup folder, etc.? And is `D:` a disk on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Is your database really called `garment.mdf` on the server side? Is that the **logical** database name?

I find that highly unlikely.

If you want to backup from the server, you need to use the **logical database name** (e.g. `Garment`) - but **NOT** the actual **file name**!

So try this code:

```
// Define a Backup object variable.
Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

// Specify the type of backup, the description, the name, and the database to be backed up.
sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "Backup of 'Garment' on " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "FullBackUp";
sqlBackup.Database = "Garment";   // use the **LOGICAL** database name here!
sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

// Declare a BackupDeviceItem
BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem("D:\\SQLBackup" + "Garment.bak", DeviceType.File);

// Define Server connection
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(".\\SQLEXPRESS");

Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
sqlServer.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 60 * 60;

Database db = sqlServer.Databases["Garment"];  // use the LOGICAL database name!

// Add the device to the Backup object.
sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);

// Set the Incremental property to False to specify that this is a full database backup.
sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

// Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete.
sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;
sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

// Run SqlBackup to perform the full database backup on the instance of SQL Server.
sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);

// Remove the backup device from the Backup object.
sqlBackup.Devices.Remove(deviceItem);
```